# "a constant value is expected" error in switch statement in c#

Tags: c#

```
switch (Rotation.ToString())
{                  
    case (-Math.PI / 2).ToString():
    // some code
    break;
}
```

The compiler complains about `(-Math.PI / 2).ToString()`, "a constant value is expected"
Isn't that a constant?

Comment: Why not just use the numerical values in the `switch` statement?

Comment: @Evan: You can't use a `double` in a switch statement, due to the pitfalls Jon suggests.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Oh, right. I forgot. But removing the `ToString` from the case will cause a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 6):

No method call is a constant value.

Incidentally, since `Math.PI` is a `double`, you might want to not use it in "equality" comparisons as you are doing here; there are well-documented pitfalls.

A better approach for a single test would be:

```
var target = -Math.PI / 2;
if (Math.Abs(Rotation - target) < 0.0001) {
    // some code
}
```

If there are lots of branches, without going into delegate territory, you can do something like this:

```
var specialCases = new[] { -Math.PI, -Math.PI / 2 };
var epsilon = 0.001d;
var index = specialCases.Select((d, i) => Math.Abs(Rotation - d) < epsilon ? i : -1)
                        .Where(i => i != -1).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();

switch (index) {
    case 0: // -Math.PI
    break;
    case 1: // -Math.PI / 2
    break;
    default: // No match
    break;
}
```

Not the best use of LINQ, but it will allow you to get back to `switch` territory with a minimum of tinkering.

Comment: It **is** constant though, just that the compiler has no way of knowing that.

Comment: It won't work without `ToString` because he's comparing it to a `string` value. +1, though, for the general response.

Comment: @Alxandr: It is not a constant from all the viewpoints except the human one. Try `ReferenceEquals(Math.PI.ToString(), Math.PI.ToString())`.

Comment: It won't work without `ToString()`. You can't switch on floating point types.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah I know that, but afaik, swhich-case works fine with strings, no? So you don't need ReferenceEquals, only Equals, which get's translated into "would a human say this is the same as?" more or less at least.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I completely glossed over that at first, but the current answer provides specific solutions. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Alxandr: `Math.PI.ToString()` could produce a different value in Europe than it will in the United States, so the value cannot be pre-calculated by the compiler into a constant string literal and then used later by someone who may be in a different country to check against a string that they just generated.

Answer (score 1):

Jon answers the gist of the question: the result of a method call is never considered to be a `constant` from the compiler's perspective. You can do this:

```
string i = (-Math.PI / 2).ToString();
switch(i)
{
    case "-1.5707963267949": Console.WriteLine("hi");
        break;
}
```

However, bear in mind that `double.ToString()` may produce different results depending on the current culture info. (Hence the reason it cannot be constant.) So you're probably better off using the `double` value directly and, depending on the size of your switch statement, either creating a few `if/else` statements, or creating a `Dictionary` keyed on the constant value you're trying to match.

And of course, Jon's initial warning still holds true: while doing floating-point logic, you could very easily end up with a value that *should* be `-pi/2`, but which isn't *exactly* `-pi/2`, in which case your check will fail. Here be dragons.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
const var SomeVar = (-Math.PI / 2).ToString();
switch (Rotation.ToString())
{                  
    case SomeVar:
        // some code
    break;
}
```